# retrieve the number of products in a category with Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am doing a first job on prestashop 1.7
I am currently trying to display a list of product categories

```
   $root_category_id = Context::getContext()->shop->getCategory();
        $category_tree = Category::getNestedCategories($root_category_id);
        $category_array = [];
        foreach ($category_tree[2]["children"] as $cat) {
 
            array_push($category_array, $cat);
        }
```

So far, it works.
But, my problem is that I will also want to retrieve the number of products in each of the associated categories to display them with the name of the category

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. If you want an answer here, especially for such a specific subject, you must show what you already tried, even if it sounds bad. Keep in mind that you are here to get help or help others, you will never have an "out of the box" solution.
Anyway, you can find your answer by scoured the class `category` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Check function getProducts() in classes/Category.php

```
public function getProducts(
        $idLang,
        $p,
        $n,
        $orderyBy = null,
        $orderWay = null,
        $getTotal = false, // To return count of products, pass this parameter as true
        $active = true,
        $random = false,
        $randomNumberProducts = 1,
        $checkAccess = true,
        Context $context = null
    )
```